# Can't get vertical align to work with img tag inside of a list

Tags: html, css, layout, vertical-alignment

Pretty basic question - I can't seem to vertically align an icon inside of a list.

My css looks likes this:

```
#top_content img {
float: left;
}

#top_content ul {
float: right;
}

#top_content li img {
vertical-align: sub;

}

#top_content li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
}

#top_content li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #7aa807;
}
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="top_content">
<ul>
<li><img src="../img/mail_ico.png" alt="#"><a href="#"><strong>(1 New)</strong></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `line-height` to it:

```
#top_content img {
  float: left;
  line-height:20px; /* adjust accordingly */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Expecting vertical-align to work properly :)  In your case would it be possible to set mail_ico.png as a background image on the <a>?  That's how I handle cases where the vertical position of an image is important in a design.

Answer (score 1):

Don't `float` the image. It will no longer be `inline` behavior, that is what is causing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`float: left` is basicly canceling out the effect of `vertical-align`. `vertical-align` c ontrols the alignment of an in-line element to other in-line elements on the same text line. `float: left` makes the `img` a block element, on which `vertical-align` has no effect.